# Generating random points within sub geometries using st_sample from the sf package

Tags: r, for-loop, random, r-sf, terra

Basically I'm trying to create 5 random spatial points within polgons of a shapefile. I am trying to use `st_sample()` from the `sf` package, but am having trouble with my `for` loop.

Example:

```
library(terra)
library(sf)

#10 polygons
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
v <- v[c(1:10)] 

#Empty list to store values
empty_list <- list()

#for loop
for(i in 1:length(v$ID_1)){
  
  empty_list[i] <- st_sample(x = v[i,], size = 5, 
                             type = "random", exact =T, by_polygon = T)
}
```

The loop seems fairly simple and straightforward. I think the issue is that `st_sample()` is only storing 1 value with each iteration. Should I use something other than a list to store output values, or is a `for` loop not the correct option here?

Comment: Hi @seak23. I hope my answer below meets your need. If so, please consider marking this response as accepted and/or upvoted. If not, please tell me what is wrong. Cheers.

Comment: @lovalery thank you so much! Can you explain a little why we are providing a vector to the size argument and not just a single number representing the number of points to generate per polygon?

Comment: Hi @seak23. Glad I could help you. Yes for sure, I can give you some more explanations. If you only specify a value for the `size` argument, say 5, `st_sample()` will only generate 5 points over the entire extent of the `sf` object. By doing this, you only get 5 points spread over the whole extent without taking into account each polygon individually.

Comment: If you want to have 5 points in each polygon, you need to specify a vector. Specifying a vector "tells" the `st_sample()` function that you want to fill each individual polygon. There are then two possibilities: (i) you can specify a vector whose length is equal to the number of polygons by coding `size = rep(5, 10)` or more generally `size = rep(5, nrow(v_sf))`;

Comment: (ii) the alternative solution (i.e. the one I suggested in my answer below) is to specify a vector with just two values `size = c(5,5)` and this vector will be automatically "recycled" in order to fill all the polygons  present in your `sf` object with 5 points. I hope you will find these comments useful and wish you the best in your work. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to perform a `for` loop. You only need to specify a vector for the `size` argument of the `st_sample()` function.

I don't know why you want to start with a `SpatVector` but I also gave you the code to convert the object to an `sf` class object because the `st_sample()` function expects an `sf` or `sfc` class object

So please, find the reprex below.

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(terra)
library(sf)

# Convert 'SpatVector' into 'sf' object
v_sf <- st_as_sf(v)

# Create the random points (here, 5 random points for each polygon)
set.seed(452)
points <- st_sample(v_sf, size = c(5,5), type = "random")
```

- Output

```r
plot(st_geometry(v_sf))
plot(points, pch = 20, add= TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>